# Rails Ancestry can't get capital

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, ancestry

I am using ancestry gem in rails 6 on my Location model. On the model, I have a location_type enum.

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord

    enum location_type: ["continent", "country", "state", "state_capital", "country_and_state_capital", "city" ]
```

when a record has a location type of country I would like to find its "country_and_state_capital" as its country_capital in the location model

```
def country_capital
   self.descendants.where(location_type: "country_and_state_capital")
end
```

and then call its data in the view

currently when I do this it just shows location

```
Location Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "locations".* FROM "locations" WHERE "locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/locations/show.html.erb:25
```

any idea what I can do to just access the one record

Comment: What SQL do you get if you change your code to `self.descendants` ?

Comment: Hi @BenTrewern, I get #<Location::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007ffd44337928>

Comment: But what SQL do you receive in your logs?